# некорректный перевод из int в char

Tags: c, char

Очень тупой вопрос, но не могу нормальный результат получить. Нужно перевести числа из диапазона `10 .. 99` (числа хранятся в `int`) в `char`. В итоге должна быть строка из чисел данного диапазона, которая потом будет записана в файл.

Конструкции типа:

```
int a = 65;
char ch = 65;
```

или

```
int a = 65;
char ch = (char)a;
```

не работают (в строке - ASCII символы).
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В смысле не работают? Перевод целого типа в другой целый тип - одно, а перевод любого целого типа в строку - совсем другое. Используйте sprintf() к примеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вам нужно переводить многозначные числа, просто в `char` их не перевести, только в строку (массив `char`).

Раз вы работаете в C, то просто выделяйте память под строку и используйте `sprintf` (или безопасные аналоги):

```
char s[20]; // Для двузначного хватит и s[3] - не забываем о нулевом символе
sprintf(s,"%d",a);
```

Вариант с `itoa` плох тем, что это - **не**стандартная функция.

Для конкретно двузначных чисел можно и свой код написать:

```
char s[3] = {0}; // Чтоб занулить завершающий символ
s[0] = '0' + a/10;
s[1] = '0' + a%10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, чтобы перевести цифру в char, в си делают так:

```
int a = 8;
char c = a + '0'; // просто добавляем код '0'
```

Так же в stdlib.h есть специальные функции:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

   char buff[20];
   int a = 12345;
   char *p;

   p = itoa(a, buff, 10); // где 10 - система счисления
}
```

Comment: Ваш первый пример не годится, когда a >= 10.

Comment: Поэтому я написал "цифру", а не число

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю суть проблемы.
Проверил - у меня корректно сработали все варианты:

```
int a = 65;
char c = 65;

int a = 65;
char c = a;
```

результат:

```
a   65  int
c   65 'A'  char
```

Другое дело, что если под "Нужно перевести числа из диапазона 10 .. 99 (числа хранятся в int) в char" понимается

1) перевод числа в строку,

тогда тут нужен не `char`, а минимум `char[3]`, и можно использовать функцию itoa

```
int a = 57;
char c[3];
itoa(a, (char*)c, 10);
```

2) перевод числа в цифру

но тогда только от 0 до 9 будет работать, все остальное начнёт выдавать символы

```
int a = 3;
char c = '0' + a;
```

3) перевод цифры в строку

но тогда только от 0 до 9 будет работать

```
int a = 3;
char c[2];
с[0] = '0' + a;
с[1] = '\0';
```

Лучше уточни, где именно у тебя не сработало.